# XPATH: Providing a default response if an array search does not find the required item?

Tags: xpath

This is a problem that I am facing in Oracle Integration Cloud when using the assignment expression editor.
In my problem, I get records from a DB table that have name/value columns. I have variables for the possible names and want to assign the values in an assign action: varParticipantId, varOrgId, varPersonId (there are more).  So, if the NAME column is ParticpantId and the VALUE column is 12345 then I want to set the variable varParticipantId = 12345.

If I have a result from the table like this (SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE ID = "AAAA"), then my xpath works and varParticipantId is set to the result of the XPATH query, 12345.

| ID | NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAAA | ParticipantId | 12345 |
| AAAA | OrgId | 54321 |

The XML would look like this (simplified):

```
<response>
    <records>
        <id>AAAA</id>
        <name>ParticipantId</name>
        <value>12345</value>
    </records>
    <records>
        <id>AAAA</id>
        <name>OrgId</name>
        <value>54321</value>
    </records>
</response>
```

This is the assignment expression (simplified):
$getRefs/getResponse/....../records[name=‘ParticpantId’]/value

However if the result set doesn’t have the record I’m looking for then it fails, e.g. (SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE ID = "BBBB")

| ID | NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BBBB | OrgId | 98765 |

```
<response>
    <records>
        <id>BBBB</id>
        <name>OrgId</name>
        <value>98765</value>
    </records>
</response>
```

What I want to do in this case is to set the variable varParticipantId = “”, i.e. have a default return of null if records[name=‘xxxxxx’] is not found. Is this doable with XPATH?

This is the XPATH query

$getRefs/getResponse/....../records[name=‘ParticpantId’]/value

If no record with name = ParticpantId, I get this error

```
summary=<summary>The &lt;from> value is invalid.Xpath expression associated with &lt;from> in copy assign activity is invalid.There is an user error that results in missing element value(s) in the xpath query.</summary>,activity=<activity>29726865-BpAss30-BpSeq7.3-54</activity>,query=<query>$messagecontext_37.parameters/../nsmpr8:getResponse/nsmpr8:components.schemas.get-response-wrapper/nsmpr0:records[(nsmpr3:referenceAttributeName = “ParticpantId”)]/nsmpr3:referenceAttributeValue_0x737063_</query>
```

Comment: With XPath questions, you should always specify which XPath version is in use.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, I would have done so except that Oracle doesn’t seem to expose that detail. Some googling suggests it might be 2.0 but I can’t state that definitively.

Comment: If they don't say, then it's probably 1.0 - which makes it difficult.

Comment: @MichaelKay https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E68885_01/doc.731/e68892/dev_xpath_functions.htm shows that it has partial XPath2 capabilities

Comment: I don't see any evidence of 2.0 capabilities on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted this answer and subsequently withdrew it. Putting the XPATH expression inside the string() function returns "" if the expression evaluates to null. Makes sense.

Comment: But if the expression selects multiple nodes, then string() in XPath 1.0 will give the string value of the first node and ignore all the others, which doesn't feel like it meets the requirement.

Comment: @MichaelKay This actually works for me. Since I am storing variable values in the DB between invocations, each variable name is unique, so there will be either 0 or 1 occurrences for each key - <id>+<name>.